# RewriteRule, how do I include entities?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, movabletype

I am tring to clean up url for my blog's search script using RewriteRule in .htaccess

Clean searching URL: (xxx= tag name ex. apple)

```
http://myblog.com/news/xxx/
```

Regular Search URL script path:

```
http://myblog.com/scripts/search.cgi?blog_id=4&tag=xxx&limit=10 [L]
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /scripts/search.cgi?blog_id=4&tag=$1&limit=10 [L]
```

This works on majority of the words except when the word has '&'.
When entered as url '&' is converted as entity '%26' but when that is entered in to the browser as `http://myblog.com/news/D%26G/` my .htaccess only recognizes 'D' and skips beyond.

How do I include '%26'in my RewriteRule?

I use Movable Type 5 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [*B* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to have the values of backreferences escaped:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /scripts/search.cgi?blog_id=4&tag=$1&limit=10 [L,B]
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.  How do I incorporate B flag to my rule? I am novice.